macOS 12.7.4: compile error from Xcode14.2 module "map"
On macOS 12.7.4, I'm trying to port from linux a beloved old app for small-scale scientific data processing (used by me for about 40 years on various platforms), called eXtrema.
After struggling with autotools (brew: "libtool 2.4.7") that is used in the linux distro, I reached make, which produces a number of successful C++ compiles, but finally a C++ compile error from a module called "map" in Xcode 14.2.  I now show here one of 22 successful compiles of such modules, then the error occurs ...
MacBook-Pro:build-macOS-12.7.4-x86 andy$ ../configure --prefix=/tmp/eXtrema --with-wx-config=/usr/local/share/wxWidgets-3.2.5/build/wx-config
MacBook-Pro:build-macOS-12.7.4-x86 andy$ make 

   < … About 21 successful compiles of source modules, then … >

    /bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -std=gnu++11 -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"extrema\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"extrema\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"4.7.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"extrema\ 4.7.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"edward.sternin@brocku.ca\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"https://www.physics.brocku.ca/Labs/extrema/\" -DPACKAGE=\"extrema\" -DVERSION=\"4.7.0\" -DHAVE_STDIO_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -I. -I../../src   -DNDEBUG -I../../src -I../../src/Commands -I../../src/Expression -I../../src/Functions -I../../src/Graphics -I../../src/Operators -I../../src/Parsing -I../../src/Utilities -I../../src/Variables -I../../src/wxForms -I/usr/local/share/wxWidgets-3.2.5/build/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-3.2 -I/usr/local/share/wxWidgets-3.2.5/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXMAC__ -D__WXOSX__ -D__WXOSX_COCOA__    -g -O2 -MT Commands/CMD_density.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o Commands/CMD_density.lo ../../src/Commands/CMD_density.cpp &&\
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
libtool: compile:  g++ -std=gnu++11 -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"extrema\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"extrema\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"4.7.0\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"extrema 4.7.0\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"edward.sternin@brocku.ca\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"https://www.physics.brocku.ca/Labs/extrema/\" -DPACKAGE=\"extrema\" -DVERSION=\"4.7.0\" -DHAVE_STDIO_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -I. -I../../src -DNDEBUG -I../../src -I../../src/Commands -I../../src/Expression -I../../src/Functions -I../../src/Graphics -I../../src/Operators -I../../src/Parsing -I../../src/Utilities -I../../src/Variables -I../../src/wxForms -I/usr/local/share/wxWidgets-3.2.5/build/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-3.2 -I/usr/local/share/wxWidgets-3.2.5/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXMAC__ -D__WXOSX__ -D__WXOSX_COCOA__ -g -O2 -MT Commands/CMD_density.lo -MD -MP -MF Commands/.deps/CMD_density.Tpo -c ../../src/Commands/CMD_density.cpp -o Commands/CMD_density.o
depbase=`echo Commands/CMD_destroy.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
    /bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -std=gnu++11 -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"extrema\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"extrema\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"4.7.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"extrema\ 4.7.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"edward.sternin@brocku.ca\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"https://www.physics.brocku.ca/Labs/extrema/\" -DPACKAGE=\"extrema\" -DVERSION=\"4.7.0\" -DHAVE_STDIO_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -I. -I../../src   -DNDEBUG -I../../src -I../../src/Commands -I../../src/Expression -I../../src/Functions -I../../src/Graphics -I../../src/Operators -I../../src/Parsing -I../../src/Utilities -I../../src/Variables -I../../src/wxForms -I/usr/local/share/wxWidgets-3.2.5/build/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-3.2 -I/usr/local/share/wxWidgets-3.2.5/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXMAC__ -D__WXOSX__ -D__WXOSX_COCOA__    -g -O2 -MT Commands/CMD_destroy.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o Commands/CMD_destroy.lo ../../src/Commands/CMD_destroy.cpp &&\
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
libtool: compile:  g++ -std=gnu++11 -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"extrema\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"extrema\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"4.7.0\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"extrema 4.7.0\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"edward.sternin@brocku.ca\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"https://www.physics.brocku.ca/Labs/extrema/\" -DPACKAGE=\"extrema\" -DVERSION=\"4.7.0\" -DHAVE_STDIO_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -I. -I../../src -DNDEBUG -I../../src -I../../src/Commands -I../../src/Expression -I../../src/Functions -I../../src/Graphics -I../../src/Operators -I../../src/Parsing -I../../src/Utilities -I../../src/Variables -I../../src/wxForms -I/usr/local/share/wxWidgets-3.2.5/build/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-3.2 -I/usr/local/share/wxWidgets-3.2.5/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXMAC__ -D__WXOSX__ -D__WXOSX_COCOA__ -g -O2 -MT Commands/CMD_destroy.lo -MD -MP -MF Commands/.deps/CMD_destroy.Tpo -c ../../src/Commands/CMD_destroy.cpp -o Commands/CMD_destroy.o
In file included from ../../src/Commands/CMD_destroy.cpp:20:
In file included from ../../src/Commands/CMD_destroy.h:21:
In file included from ../../src/Commands/Command.h:21:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/map:726:17: error: no viable overloaded '='
        __ref() = __v.__get_value();


At source code CMD_destroy.cpp:20, we see...
     18 #include "wx/wx.h"
     19 
     20 #include "CMD_destroy.h"

and at CMD_destroy.h:21 ...
     18 #ifndef EX_DESTROYCOMMAND
     19 #define EX_DESTROYCOMMAND
     20 
     21 #include "Command.h"
     22 

and at Commands/Command.h:21 ...
     18 #ifndef CMD_COMMAND
     19 #define CMD_COMMAND
     20 
     21 #include <map>
     22 #include <vector>
     23 #include <cmath>

The context of the error generating line of Xcode is [_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY] (What is _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY?)
    723     _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    724     __value_type& operator=(const __value_type& __v)
    725     {
    726         __ref() = __v.__get_value();
    727         return *this;
    728     }
    729 


That cited post doesn't much help the likes of me, in this context.
Except it seems to suggest that clang must be used for such Xcode stuff
(if indeed a gnu alternative for g++ even exists), so I note that I did
also install the Command Line Tools for XCode 14.2, (because there was an
obsolete version lying around from before they got imbedded in the Xcode app),
and I include this …
MacBook-Pro:Nrotstar andy$ g++ --version
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

... and this ...
MacBook-Pro:build-macOS-12.7.4-x86 andy$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/opt/libtool/libexec/gnubin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

In addition to the above error, I also get quite a few compile "notes" from this and other modules in that Xcode directory, such as:
v1/__tree:1662:39: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__value_type<const wxString, NumericVariable *>::operator=' requested here
            __cache.__get()->__value_ = *__first;
                                      ^


——————
I guess I should also mention that I got this warning below from autotools, installed by brew.
Brew fortunately compensates for a name conflict between libtool in autotools and libtool in Xcode,for which this was needed (the first line of which I had to ad-lib):
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/libtool/2.4.7/bin/glibtoolize /opt/local/bin/glibtoolize 

MacBook-Pro:eXtrema-4.7.0 andy$ PATH="/usr/local/opt/libtool/libexec/gnubin:$PATH" 
MacBook-Pro:eXtrema-4.7.0 andy$ libtoolize
MacBook-Pro:eXtrema-4.7.0 andy$ aclocal
MacBook-Pro:eXtrema-4.7.0 andy$ autoheader


... before I got this ...
MacBook-Pro:eXtrema-4.7.0 andy$ autoreconf --install
configure.ac:72: warning: The macro 'AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
configure.ac:72: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:204: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
m4/mud.m4:8: AX_CHECK_MUD is expanded from...
configure.ac:72: the top level
configure.ac:73: warning: The macro 'AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
configure.ac:73: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:204: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
m4/minuit.m4:8: AX_CHECK_MINUIT is expanded from...
configure.ac:73: the top level
MacBook-Pro:eXtrema-4.7.0 andy$ which autoupdate
/opt/local/bin/autoupdate

Although autoupdate doesn't solve this completely,
@bagder sez: that AC_HELP_STRING is only deprecated,
and anyway can be replaced by AS_HELP_STRING.
I'm beginning to appreciate this: @jww sez "Autotools absolutely sucks."
But autotools is inherited from the linux distro…
Helpful suggestions would be most welcome!
thanks
Andy
I was expecting (actually held faint hope for) an error-free compile.
The context checks that online advice suggested are mentioned above.

Your problems seem mostly to arise from C++ language issues, not, for the most part, the Autotools or make.  I've added the C++ tag, and removed [visibility] to make room.

The relevant code is calling operator=, so the issue is in code you're not showing (scroll up in your terminal until the errors are in your code and not the standard library).  [Edit] your question with a [mcve].

Thanks Stephen, but there are no error messages at all appearing above the one I show — only about 22 successful compilations of other source modules in that same Xcode app directory.  As the clip shows, the error occurs while compiling this module in the app: ../../src/Commands/CMD_destroy.cpp

I added more context to the original question. All 22 previous modules compiled successfully have the same short and simple include chain.

Additional note: you should not autoreconf without need.  The Autotools model assumes that the generated Autotools scripts and ancillary files will be distributed in the source package, such that people can build the project without having the Autotools executables (including autoreconf) themselves.  If you don't modify the build system then you should not need to autoreconf.  When you do autoreconf, you expose yourself to issues around differences between Autotools versions.

Understood, John — thanks.  But in this situation where I'm using a linux distro to port onto macOS, is it reasonable to still hope  that "people can build the project without having the Autotools executables"?

(Anyway, even this linux distro instructs us to start on linux with autoreconf --install.)
